# css has to apply only one seat <li> ( restrict multiple select)

Tags: javascript, jquery

bus reservation

The following code generate multilpe `<li>` and when the user click seats, the selected seats css will change. but **i want to restrict the multiple selection. the user has to be allow  to select only one seat, if he select second `<li>` (seat) , then the first one has to go unselect**

DEMO : http://demo.techbrij.com/780/seat-reservation-jquery-demo.php

CODE : http://techbrij.com/seat-reservation-with-jquery

```
    $(function () {
        var settings = {
            rows: 6,
            cols: 6,
            rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
            colCssPrefix: 'col-',
            seatWidth: 30,
            seatHeight: 30,
            seatCss: 'seat',
            selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
            selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
        };

        var init = function (reservedSeat) {
            var str = [], seatNo, className;
            for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {

                    seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);   // Seat No  eg : seatNo = 0+0*0+1 (1)
                    className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString(); // Class each seat class Name=seat row-0 col-0

                    if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
                        className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                    }

                    str.push('<li onclick="gettable('+ seatNo+')" class="' + className  +" table"+seatNo+ '">' 

                                +'<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a>' +
                              '</li>');
                }
            }
            $('#place').html(str.join(''));
        };




        var bookedSeats = [5, 10, 25];
        init(bookedSeats);


        $('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)){
            alert('This seat is already reserved');
        }
        else{
            $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);


            }
        });
```

Comment: can you also please provide your html/css perhaps using something like http://jsfiddle.com/

Comment: please show your code in jsfiddle.com

Comment: http://demo.techbrij.com/780/seat-reservation-jquery-demo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the class from all elements, then add it to the selected one.

```
$('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)){
            alert('This seat is already reserved');
        }
        else{
            $('.' + settings.seatCss).removeClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
            $(this).addClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the else part to:

```
 else{
      $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
      $(".settings.selectingSeatCss").not(this).removeClass('settings.selectingSeatCss');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the code in `click()` event with this one.

```
$('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {
   $(this).addClass(settings.selectedSeatCss).siblings(this).removeClass(settings.selectedSeatCss);
});
```

working [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/yeyizowa/1/edit). Hope it helps you.